# I'm currently writing a black jack game and I am having problems with passing my code onto the "calculating_scores" function

Tags: python

Can anyone help me fix my issue with getting my code to pass onto the calculating_scores function without my coding wanting to loop back up every time I enter something into the `another_card = input("Type 'y' if you'd like another card:\n")`

```
 def play():
        global game_continue
        user_cards = []
        dealer_cards = []
        for _ in range(2):
            user_cards.append(deal_cards())
            dealer_cards.append(deal_cards())
    
        total_user = sum(user_cards)
        print(f"You got the cards: {user_cards}, giving you a total of {total_user}\n")
        print(f"The dealer got the card: {dealer_cards[0]}\n")
    
        while game_continue:
            another_card = input("Type 'y' if you'd like another card:\n")
            if another_card == "yes" or another_card == "y":
                user_cards.append(deal_cards())
                new_user_total = sum(user_cards)
                print(f"You have the cards, {user_cards}, giving you a total of: {new_user_total}")
                dealer_total = dealer_cards[0] + dealer_cards[1]
                print(f"The dealers second card was {dealer_cards[1]}, giving him a total of {dealer_total}")
                calculating_scores(card_list=user_cards)
            elif another_card == "no" or another_card == "n":
                game_continue = False
                dealer_total = dealer_cards[0] + dealer_cards[1]
                print(f"The second dealers card was a {dealer_cards[1]} giving him a total of {dealer_total}")
                calculating_scores(card_list=user_cards)
            else:
                print("Sorry this is an invalid option!")
            # 10:16pm altering the arguments called after calculating_score to make the program properly function
    
    
    def calculating_scores(card_list):
        if sum(card_list) == 21:
            return "Dealer won blackjack!"
        if 11 in card_list and sum(card_list) > 21:
            card_list.remove(11)
            card_list.append(1)
        return sum(card_list)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking, but a few notes:

You call `calculating_scores` but ignore its return value.

`calculating_scores` should just calculate the score - not determine if there is a winner.

There should be 2 loops. One for the user that goes until their score is greater than 21 or they say no more cards. And one for the dealer - who should take cards until their score is >= 17.

I would just have `play()` return the scores. Then print the winner info elsewhere.

Something like this:

```
def play():
    user_cards = [deal_cards(), deal_cards()]
    dealer_cards = [deal_cards(), deal_cards()]
    user_total = calculating_scores(user_cards)
    print(f"You got the cards: {user_cards}, giving you a total of {user_total}\n")
    print(f"The dealer got the card: {dealer_cards[0]}\n")
    
    while user_total < 21:
        another_card = input("Type 'y' if you'd like another card:\n")
        if another_card == "yes" or another_card == "y":
            user_cards.append(deal_cards())
            user_total = calculating_scores(user_cards)
            print(f"You have the cards, {user_cards}, giving you a total of: {user_total}")
        else:
            break
    dealer_total = calculating_scores(dealer_cards)
    print(f"The dealers second card was {dealer_cards[-1]}, giving him a total of {dealer_total}")
    while dealer_total <= 17:
        dealer_cards.append(deal_cards())
        dealer_total = calculating_scores(dealer_cards)
        print(f"The dealers next card was {dealer_cards[-1]}, giving him a total of {dealer_total}")

    return (user_total, dealer_total)

def calculating_scores(card_list):
    while 11 in card_list and sum(card_list) > 21:
        card_list.remove(11)
        card_list.append(1)
    return sum(card_list)
```